# Filtering year while using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to use ggplot, to have a attractive plot between the year and codes.

My column with date looks like this 1990-10-20 ; 2000-10-28 ..

I wanted to plot all the year after 2000.

Below is the code, i have tried, could anyone help how i can look for year after 2000 and plot my graph.

```
count <- c %>%
  group_by(Date, Code) %>%
  summarise(count=n())

ggplot(count, aes(Date, count))+
geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Comment: Both you and the single respondent are committing the venal sin of naming your data objects with the uninformative and confusing names of existing R functions.

Comment: I am sorry, dint understan you

Comment: `c` is a function. `count` is a function. DO NOT name your data objects with the names of R functions. Sorry for using a religious term. Roman Catholic morality has a distinction between 'venal' and 'mortal' sins. Venal sins are lesser in the Catholic schema. (I'm not particularly religious, but the terminology has seeped into general English usage.)

Comment: @42 committed the venial sin of writing "venal" when he meant "venial".

Comment: Kind of a reverse instance of Muphry's Law.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(lubridate)

count %>%
  filter(year(Date) > 2000) %>%  
  ggplot(aes(Date, count))+
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

For a range of years:

```
count %>% # BAD OBJECT NAME - RECITE 10 HAIL MARYS
  filter(year(Date) >= 2012 & year(Date) <= 2014 <) %>%  
  ggplot(aes(Date, count))+
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

You could also see `?lubridate::between` for other ways, if your left and right limits are themselves dates.

Comment: could you tell me how I could do it with ranges ?

Comment: eg: 2012 to 2014